# Specify strict 'order by' in WordPress query

Tags: wp-query, database, wpdb, get-posts, order

I have a custom post type called `Employees` where an employee's name is the `post_title` of each post.

I am trying to figure out how I would sort the `post_title` column by last name.

So for instance, if we have the following post entries:

`1. Justin Bieber
2. Selena Gomez
3. Jessica Alba
4. Nicholas Cage`

The query would contain the entire list of employees sorted by last name, so:

`1. Jessica Alba
2. Justin Bieber
3. Nicholas Cage
4. Selena Gomez`

Anybody? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort).  Your callback function would need to determine the last names and sort by them.

So, for instance:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' = 'Employees',
);
$employees = get_posts( $args );
usort( $employees, 'wp91501_sort_employees' );
```

and then your callback might be:

```
function wp91501_sort_employees( $a, $b ) {

    // split the names into arrays
    $a_name = explode( ' ', $a->post_title );
    $b_name = explode( ' ', $b->post_title );

    // get the last name from the $x_name arrays
    $a_last_name = end( $a_name );
    $b_last_name = end( $b_name );

    if( $a_last_name == $b_last_name ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a_last_name < $b_last_name ) ? -1 : 1 ;
}
```

Note that this is a *very* simple comparison -- if the employee has a double last name with no hyphen (for instance, "John Smythe Jones") then it'll get sorted according to the very last part of the name (in the example, "Jones").

An easier option might be to enter the employees in the form 'LastName, FirstName', which would allow you to just sort by `post_title ASC`.  But then you'd need to filter `the_title` if you wanted to display the title as 'FirstName LastName'.

Comment: Not sure if I'm implementing this right but before the `usort`, I `print_r($employees)` and it returns all entries, but after `usort` it just returns 1.

Comment: Whoops, I wasn't calling `usort()` quite right.  I've fixed the code above; the fix is to change `$employees = usort( $employees, 'wp91501_sort_employees' );` to `usort( $employees, 'wp91501_sort_employees' );` .  Sorry for the confusion.